Failed to construct a Palindromic Shellcode
To exploit the buffer overflow vulnerability in a challenge program, I need to craft a payload that satisfies a palindrome check and executes arbitrary code. This requires creating a palindromic shellcode, which is a sequence of instructions that reads the same forwards and backwards.
A isPalin
function checks if the input string is a palindrome. If it is, the program copies the string into a buffer of 128 bytes using strcpy, which does not perform bounds checking. This allows for a buffer overflow if the input exceeds 128 bytes. To exploit this, the input must be a palindrome and contain shellcode that, when executed, spawn a shell.
In my research I found that creating palindromic shellcode is complex because the instructions must be valid and meaningful in both directions. One approach is to design a sequence where the first half sets up the necessary state, and the second half is a mirror image that either complements the first half or is a no-op, but I have no clue how to do this..
Any solutions?

Can't you just have normal shellcode followed by the same thing in reverse?

I've tried normal shellcode followed by the same thing in reverse, it doesn't pass the palindromic check

The code you posted here doesn't reverse either shellcode or return_address, so the payload you get at the end isn't a palindrome.  You need to make sure to reverse and concatenate all the components of payload.

raises an eyebrow -- note the "practical" part of Stack Overflow topicality criteria
